# Clone encrypted HDD to smaller drive

Tags: encryption, luks, clone

For my work Laptop I use full HDD encryption and I need to upgrade my 500GB HDD to a 250 SSD drive, my HDD has only around 100GB of data and is created via `encrypted LVM`.

GParted does not support LUKS encryption, so I am unable to copy (or resize) partitions.
Using dd would be great but because of the different size I might loos data.

Then only valid option I got so far is to try and [re-size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) the partition and then try a clone with dd (but seems very complicated and prone to failure).

There is any other way to clone the data on the HDD without reinstalling ?

*Based on what I have read so far I think reinstalling would be the easiest and fastest solution, but I would like to see your ideas/opinion.*

***Thank you***

Comment: Unencrypt the partition on old system. Back up data. Copy data to new disc. Encrypt new disc. ?

Answer (score 4):

So this is what I did in the end:

- *While logged in with access to unencrypted data, I copied all the data to a external HDD using rsync.*
  ATTENTION: the first attempt copied all the data, but when I checked the data 70% was in binary form (even pictures, text files etc ...) and not useful, so I erased the external HDD and start over, the second time it worked (I have no clue what was wrong the first time), but it is very very important to `DOUBLE CHECK the copied files if you plan to tamper with the original data`.
- *Make a list with all the programs installed.*
  I did it manually from "Software Center", because I wanted to have the installed history available, you can use `dpkg -l > textfile` or other commands to give you `ALL` packages installed and then reinstall them via `aptitude install $(cat <textfile>)`. Of course you need to move the `textfile` to the new installation.
- Install the same OS version in onto the new HDD, using the same name for your user account.
- Mount the external drive and copy everything to the new HDD
  ATENTION: If you do this from GUI, do not overwrite your home dir, just put it with a different name for example /home/YOURNAME.orig, and after all files are copied, go to ctrl+alt+F2, log in the machins, stop the gui (for normal ubuntu 12.04 the command is `service lightdm stop`, mv your old home on top of the new one `mv /home/YOURNAME.orig /home/YOURNAME`, and start X again `service lightdm start`.

Here you can see the power of Linux's /home dir, everything was back in place, icons, settings, applications specific settings, even cached data :), and I only had a downtime of about 4 hours (because the first copy failed).

Hope this helps, I still consider this a faster and safer approach compared to resizing the encrypted HDD.

Comment: I can complete a bit.
I followed what you did, and it worked great, thanks for the tip ! Nevertheless, i forgot copying a few stuff (like postfix configuration, etc ..)
What i ended up doing, is creating a VMWARE Image, using my old HDD as a real logical drive (really easy to do with VMWare workstation), and boot it up. I had then access to both systems, unencrypted, and could sync things easilly.
That's another really interesting option if you do not have a backup drive available.