# Optimal Ubuntu setup for taking advantage of Clonezilla?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, clonezilla

I'm having a problem regarding the cloning of my disk; Clonezilla requires as much free space as the size of my original drive. So, I decided to re-install Ubuntu manually following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation). In fact, I ended up with the setup [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuCw0.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq5ZY.jpg).

My questions are:

- Does the overall process look like ok to you? Should I do anything in
  addition / different?
- I [feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsmJX.jpg) like I ended up encrypting only the home folder, however, I would like to have every single partition encrypted. What do you think?
- Which of the partitions should I clone afterwards? Is it enough to clone the `sda5 (/)` partition?
- And finally, how to restore the corrupted / faulty partition later on?

Comment: Backup and/or redundancy is all about personal importance of data. If you have some classified military intelligence data stored on your computer, you may want to go with RAID and daily  backups to external drive. On the other hand, if all you have is music and films, you may want to avoid backup and redundancy completely to take full advantage of disk space.

Comment: do you wish to clone the entire disk or only some partition?

Comment: @Ron I want to clone my entire disk (`/dev/sda` - 320GB), which is fully encrypted, yet almost empty (a fresh Ubuntu install, say). What's your opinion about this: `http://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk` solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your partitions look ok.
2. If you want to enable full disk encryption *after* installation, most probably you will have to reinstall ubuntu. There is a good reference on different options you have for disk encryption [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto). There are also tools like [Cryptkeeper](http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/03/create-an-encrypted-folder-in-ubuntu-with-cryptkeeper/), [DM-Crypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-dm-crypt-to-create-an-encrypted-volume-on-an-ubuntu-vps), and [LUKS](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/) which you could try. And yes, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-syste%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bm-to-a-different-hard-disk) method works well and is comparatively easier to do.

   In addition if you want to clone your encrypted drives to smaller drivers have a look at [ResizeEncryptedPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) docs from ubuntu. there are [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546908/linux-clone-encrypted-drive-to-smaller-drive) resources [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261140/clone-encrypted-hdd-to-smaller-drive) in Ask Ubuntu as well. Do go through them before making a final call.
3. That depends on what all things you want to backup.
4. Depends on the extend of damage to the partition. Sometime it will be as easy as booting in live USB/CD and `automatically fix` the partition. But in more serious damages it might be even impossible to recover data.

Comment: cool! And what if I choose to follow Ubuntu's default installation process with full partition encryption? Would you then suggest this process (`http://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-syste‌​m-to-a-different-hard-disk`) instead? Why? Why not?

Comment: I have not tried this but I feel using live CD will be easier but, with a possible [loss](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/clone-encrypted-hard-drive-57682.html) of encryption (again I am not too sure about this), but Clonezilla might [retain](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058427) encyption

Comment: ok. I'll try it then. Unfortunately, apart from retaining encryption, Clonezilla also considers all blank sectors, ending up with an image as big as my source drive :(

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the overall process look like ok to you? Should I do anything in
>   addition / different?

In a single word. Yes, your partitions are just Ok and more.

Putting /var on a separate partition prevents a misbehaving applications like  database server, and other log files in /var/log from consuming   the space of your disk.

Putting /tmp on a separate partition prevent some tmp files from some apps from consuming the disk space.

Putting /boot on a separate partition was needed in some old times  when machines had trouble addressing large hard drives, but this is not needed anymore. So you can get rid of this partition.

Putting /home on a separate partition can save your data, configurations ,etc.. specially if you install a new Ubuntu version. Moreover, it becomes more easy to resize your /home if you need some space. Plus it would save your data  when  you have some booting problems.

And of course you need the / partition.

> I feel like I ended up encrypting only the home folder, however, I
>   would like to have every single partition encrypted. What do you
>   think?

I'm afraid to say that you can't do a full disk encryption after you finish Installation. But anyway you still has the ability to obtain a disk encryption using many applications such `cryptsetup`,...

> Which of the partitions should I clone afterwards? Is it enough to
>   clone the sda5 (/) partition?

Now, for cloning purpose, indeed it's up to you. But you should specify your needs.

If you want to clone the full HDD then you have to clone the all partitions. If you just need your user data then you can install anyother version of Ubuntu and clone the /home. So this is related to what do you want to do in real.

> And finally, how to restore the corrupted / faulty partition later on?

Also this is directly  related to what is the fault. Those problems raise from file system errors which can be solved using `fsck` commands, and may extend to the need of installing a new Version. So to solve the problem you have first idetifying the problem, But in simple words, The paritioning module you use will help you much in being flexible for solving system errors.